# Php language class usage issue

Tags: php

My php multilanguage class returns translated text by field when i call the class. I use echo for return translated text because i fetch whole page in class and translate them in foreach. Problem is when i return translated text with echo, **$lang->Translate("PLANT")** it jumps outside where i put it. How can i solve this issue. (By the way i can't use just return it only returns 1 row of language table)

The Language Table

[image]

```
echo '
<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table table-striped table-hover">
    <thead class="thead-light">
    <tr>
        <th scope="col"></th>
        <th scope="col"><b></b></th>
        <th scope="col"><b>'.$lang->Translate("PLANT").'</b></th>
        <th scope="col" class="d-none d-sm-table-cell"><b>'.$lang->Translate("COMPANY").'</b></th>
        <th scope="col" class="d-none d-sm-table-cell"><b></b></th>
        <th scope="col" class="d-none d-sm-table-cell"><b></b></th>
        <th scope="col" class="d-none d-sm-table-cell"><b></b></th>
        <th scope="col" class="d-none d-sm-table-cell"><b></b></th>
        <th scope="col"></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
';
```

my language class

```
class Lang {

    public function Language()
    {
        static $table = array();
        static $loaded = false;
        if (!$loaded) {
            $loaded = true;
            $lang = strtoupper(substr($_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"], 0, 2));
            include("settings.php"); //DB Connection
            $sql = $MYSQLdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM language");
            $sql->execute();
            while($print = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
            {
                $field = array($print["FIELD"] => $print[$lang]); 
                array_push($table, $field);
            }
            return $table;
        } else {
            return $table;
        }
    }

    public function Translate($translate)
    {
        $table = $this->Language();
        foreach($table as $fields) {
            echo $fields[$translate];
        }
    }
}

$lang = new Lang();
```

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean by _it jumps outside where i put it_

Comment: Image a table with captions and when i put a caption for example company in table cell '.$lang->Translate("COMPANY").' like this. It shows up outside table design.

Comment: Things are JUMPING OUT because `echo` sends directly to the browser. While your table is being built in a string and later sent to the browser. You are going to have to redesign this class to get this working properly

Comment: I dont quite understand what will be returned/echo'ed when you call `$lang->Translate("PLANT")` What data will be found in your array for that call

Comment: Excatly sir, thats my issue

Comment: Can you show a small example of your `language` table please

Comment: Just string text returns what PLANT corresponds

Comment: FIELD | EN | FR
PLANT | PLANT | PLANTE

Comment: Could you add a few  rows from the table to your question, using the [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71528295/edit) link under the question

Comment: I added right now

Comment: Thanks, that makes more sence

Comment: So how do you know if you want to convert French to English or English to French

Comment: $lang = strtoupper(substr($_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"], 0, 2)); i will change it to en and fr later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As when you do this

```
$field = array($print["FIELD"] => $print[$lang]);
```

you are making an array of word,translation i.e.

```
COMPANY ENTERPRISE
PLANT   PLANTE
```

I see no reason why you cannot `return` the translation from this method I would change the method slightly as there seems to be no reason for a loop.

```
public function Translate($translate)
{
    $table = $this->Language();
    return $table[$translate];
}
```

Or even like this so you dont need to make a copy of the array

```
public function Translate($translate)
{
    return $this->Language()[$translate];
}
```

Comment: If i use return it return only first row of table.

Comment: But you are only converting ONE word at a time, so there should only be one result, surely

Comment: No in the same page i have lots of translation like 10 words but only returns first row

Comment: Yes, but you call the translate once per word right, in one call you translate `COMPANY` and in another call you translate `PLANT`

Comment: Yes sir excatly

Comment: Did you try this and see if it works

Comment: I try this right now but nothing returns

Answer (score 1):

I could go into further improvements to your class but I will focus on your particular issue.

In short change echo to return and the output will be included in your table markup:

```
public function Translate($translate)
{
    $table = $this->Language();
    foreach($table as $fields) {
        return $fields[$translate];
    }
}
```

Now that is only going to work if that function always returns 1 word because it is going to exit your foreach loop. If the foreach is not neccessary then do this instead (as now mentioned by @RiggsFolly):

```
public function Translate($translate)
{
    $table = $this->Language();
    return $table[$translate];
}
```